# How to replace newline with another character in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace newline character with another in Word 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/124759/replace-newline-character-with-another-in-word-2007)

I'm using Microsoft Word 2007

Is it possible to replace the newline character (I mean \n) with some other character?

What about vice-versa? (replacing a character with newline)

Comment: This is more something for superuser

Comment: sorry if you think it's a foolish question, but I couldn't found any solution

Comment: Did you ask on superuser.com? Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Search and replace in a word processor doesn't count.

Comment: If he wanted to know how to do this in VBA, it would be a programming question.

Comment: oh thx ... I'm new to this site

Answer (score 3):

go to find and replace, click the more >> button at the botton, under the replace section, click the "special" button.