# How to replace a word with Regular Expression in Microsoft Word 2007?

Tags: regex, microsoft-word-2007, find-and-replace

How can I replace a word with Regular Expression in Microsoft Word 2007?

For example, I want to find and replace all `\n` with some spaces.

Comment: Are these Unix newlines or Windows line endings?

Comment: Related: [Replace newline character with another in Word 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/124759/replace-newline-character-with-another-in-word-2007)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the response.
I had to use `^13` instead of `\n` in `Find What` textbox.

[image: Find and Replace]

[Reference](http://www.gmayor.com/replace_using_wildcards.htm)